# Can anyone offer some help/advice on how to correctly create an animation?

Tags: java, swing, animation, jpanel, jcomponent

So I'm creating the game of life in java but I'm having trouble with the animation part. I have the cells drawn on a JComponent which is displaying as it should but I have a start button that should start the whole animation process but nothing happens when I click the start button.

From the tutorials I have watched and research I've done I know you must have an `ActionListener` that listens on the button and an `actionPerformed()` method that holds the code to start the animation. this being said my code is as follows:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

public class GameOfLife extends JFrame {

  int PIXELSIZE = 10;
  int ROW = 75;
  int COLUMN = 75;
  Random random = new Random();
  JButton start;

  public GameOfLife() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    DrawCells cellsComp = new DrawCells();
    DrawCells buttonListener = new DrawCells();
    start = new JButton("Start");
    start.addActionListener(cellsComp);
    panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    start.setToolTipText("Click to start game of life");
    this.setTitle("Game Of Life: Java");
    this.setSize(PIXELSIZE * ROW, PIXELSIZE * COLUMN);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    panel.add(start, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    panel.add(cellsComp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    this.add(panel);
    this.setVisible(true);
  }

  private class DrawCells extends JComponent implements ActionListener {
    int x;
    int y;
    int grid[][] = new int[ROW][COLUMN];
    int updatedGrid[][] = new int[ROW][COLUMN];

    public void createGrid() {
      for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
          grid[i][j] = random.nextInt(2);
        }
      }
    }

    public void applyRules() {
      for (int i = 1; i < ROW - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < COLUMN - 1; j++) {
          int neighboursCount = 0; // used to count the neighbours of each cell

          neighboursCount += grid[i-1][j-1]; // top left
          neighboursCount += grid[i][j-1]; // top center
          neighboursCount += grid[i+1][j-1]; // top right

          neighboursCount += grid[i-1][j]; // middle left
          neighboursCount += grid[i+1][j]; // middle right

          neighboursCount += grid[i-1][j+1]; // top left
          neighboursCount += grid[i][j+1]; // top center
          neighboursCount += grid[i+1][j+1]; // top right

          // Game of Life rules:

          // Alive cells:
          if (grid[i][j] == 1) {
            // rule 1 any live cell with fewer than two live neighboours dies, as if by underpopulation
            if (neighboursCount < 2) {
              updatedGrid[i][j] = 0;
            }
            // rule 2 any live cell with two or three live neighbours, lives on to the generation
            else if (neighboursCount == 2 || neighboursCount == 3) {
              updatedGrid[i][j] = 1;
            }
            // rule 3 any live cell with more than three live neighbours dies, as if by overpopulation
            else if (neighboursCount > 3 && neighboursCount <= 8) {
              updatedGrid[i][j] = 0;
            }
            else {
              updatedGrid[i][j] = 0;
            }
          }
          // Dead cells
          else if (grid[i][j] == 0) {
            // rule 4 any dead cell with exactly three live neighbours becomes a live cell, as if by reproduction
            if (neighboursCount == 3) {
              updatedGrid[i][j] = 1;
            }
            else {
              updatedGrid[i][j] = 0;
            }
          }
        }
      }
      for (int i = 0; i < ROW; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLUMN; j++) {
          grid[i][j] = updatedGrid[i][j];
        }
      }
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      createGrid();
      Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
      for (int i = 0; i < ROW; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLUMN; j++) {
          if (grid[i][j] == 1) {
            g2.setColor(Color.RED);
            g2.fillRect(i * PIXELSIZE, j * PIXELSIZE, PIXELSIZE, PIXELSIZE);
          }
        }
      }
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      if (e.getSource() == start) {
        applyRules();
        repaint();
        thread.sleep();
      }
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    GameOfLife gol = new GameOfLife();
  }
}
```

What I'm actually asking for is a clear explanation on how to animate some code or a nice point in the right direction in what I'm missing/need to add in order to get my code animated.

Thanks in advance for the help :D

Comment: Why do you create two DrawCells? I think you can remove `buttonListener`. `paintComponent` gets called often, and at random times. I doubt you want to use `createGrid` in it. In your 'actionPerformed' method, that is what's on the EDT. What is the current state of this program when you run it?

Comment: @matt hi thanks for the help, I was meant delete that ```buttonListener``` so thanks I forgot. And about the state when I run it, it compiling and running with no errors but I will add your

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to pretend that your gui works. In your action performed you need to start the animation. A common way to do an animation in swing is to use a [Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/Timer.html).

```
Timer animation;
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  if (e.getSource() == start && animation == null) {
      createGrid();  //remove this from paint component.
      int delay = 1000; //milliseconds
      ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
              applyRules();
              repaint();
          }
      };
      animation = new Timer(delay, taskPerformer);
      animation.start();
  }
}
```

I used the anonymous class `taskPerformer` because that is from the example in the javadoc link provided.